# How can I create a function that will allow me to edit a .txt file in python?

Tags: python, function, editing

I'm trying to create a very simple function that will let me edit a file that I've already written using Python 3.5. My writing function works just fine, but I'm including it just in case it matters. It looks like this:

```
def typer():
    print("")
    print("Start typing to begin.")
    typercommand = input("  ")
    saveAs = input("Save file as: ")
    with open(saveAs, 'w') as f:
        f.write(typercommand)
    if saveAs == (""):
        commandLine()
    commandLine()
```

My editing function looks like this:

```
def edit():
    file = input("Which file do you want to edit? ")
    with open(file, 'a') as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line)
```

I then call the function using my command line function like this:

```
def commandLine():
    command = input("~$: ")
    if command == ("edit"):
        edit()
```

I don't get any errors but nothing else happens, either (I'm just redirected to my base command line). And by that I mean that I call the function and then, on the line directly beneath it, it get the prompt for the command line I made for the program (~$). What is wrong with my code and what could I do to remedy it?

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: In your `edit()` function, you open the file for writing, but try to read from it.  I'm surprised this doesn't give an error.

Comment: How much nothing do we mean? Do you get the prompts, such as "Start typing to begin"? Is there any output at all after you try to run this?

Comment: If you're redirected to the base command line it probably means there's an infinite loop when you're calling the function.

Comment: If there is no output at all, I think you're not actually calling either of these functions.

Comment: Since you are using `input()`, are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Could you please give an example session to illustrate your nothingness? (Like a copy of the output from the terminal.)  Defining the functions `def edit():` shouldn't give any output, but calling them `edit()` should do something.  (As you've written it here, `edit()` should generate an error.)

Comment: "I don't get any errors but nothing else happens".   

Please describe exactly what you expect to happen

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read from and write to a file you have to open it with mode `'r+'`, `'w+'` or `'a+'`.
Note that `'w+'` truncates the file, so you will probably need `'r+'` or `'a+'`, see the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

Something like:

```
def edit():
    file = input("Which file do you want to edit? ")
    with open(file, 'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line)

        # here you can write to file
        ...
```

**EDITED: indentation error**

Answer (score 0):

In your edit function, you are just `printing`at the standard output every line, but you are **not** writing anything.

```
def edit():

    file = input("Which file do you want to edit? ")
    with open(file, 'w+') as f:
        filetext = ""
        for line in f:
            filetext += line

        # do stuff with filetext
        ...

        # then write the file
        f.write(filetext)
```